# Comparable Comparator Java

Tags: java, comparator, comparable

Here is my Code

```
class ComparableTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        BOX[] box = new BOX[5];
        box[0] = new BOX(10,8,6); 
        box[1] = new BOX(5,10,5);
        box[2] = new BOX(8,8,8);
        box[3] = new BOX(10,20,30);
        box[4] = new BOX(1,2,3);
        Arrays.sort(box);
        for(int i=0;i<box.length;i++)
            System.out.println(box[i]);
    }
}
```

Also i have a class BOX that implements Comparable.
Now i have a few question that i would like you all to help me out with.

1.Are the methods declared in comparable interface,system defined, as in can i have any method in the comparable, or it has to be `compareTo` only?

2.I did not provide the implementation of Arrays.sort method, how does it sort my elements then?

3.When i use `Comparator` instead of `comparable`, then I use:

```
class comparatorTest
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Student[] students = new Student[5];
        Student[0] = new Student(“John”,”2000A1Ps234”,23,”Pilani”);
        Student[1] = new Student(“Meera”,”2001A1Ps234”,23,”Pilani”);
        Student[2] = new Student(“Kamal”,”2001A1Ps344”,23,”Pilani”);
        Student[3] = new Student(“Ram”,”2000A2Ps644”,23,”Pilani”);
        Student[4] = new Student(“Sham”,”2000A7Ps543”,23,”Pilani”);    
        // Sort By Name
        Comparator c1 = new studentbyname();
        Arrays.sort(students,c1);
        for(int i=0;i<students.length;i++)
            System.out.println(students[i]);
    }
}
```

//In the above code, `studentbyname implements comparator`, but box stil implements `comparable` .i.e

```
class studentbyname implements comparator
{
    public int compare(Object o1,Object o2)
    {  
        Student s1 = (Student) o1;
        Student s2 = (Student) o2;
        return s1.getName().compareTo(s2.getName());
    }
}
```

Now i am doing `Arrays.sort(students,c1)`, why am i passing c1 now?

Comment: You don't have basic knowledge on how polymorphism ,inheritance and method overloading work in java. Look those up first, and you'll understand why: u need to implement compareTo, you can pass a different number of arguments to what seems to be the same method.

Comment: You can refer http://www.digizol.com/2008/07/java-sorting-comparator-vs-comparable.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. In order to meet the **Comparable** contract, you must have at least the **compareTo** method. You may have as many addition methods in your class as you would like.
2. It sorts the elements in the **natural** order based on the **Comparable** interface. So **sort** is calling **compareTo** between the elements to see in which order to place them.
3. Providing a **Comparator** to the sort method allows **sort** to order elements that either (a) don't implement **Comparable** or (b) where you want to order them in some other order than the "natural order" as defined by the class's **Comparable** implementation.

When you pass a Comparator to sort, it calls the Comparator's compare method rather than the elements' compareTo method (if implemented).

see [What is an interface](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html)

see [Comparator](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)

see [Comparable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html)

Comment: so Comparable is like, i dont know what the right term would be, but 'system defined' that is, it has to contain compareTo right?

Comment: Comparable is an **interface**, which means that it defines a set of methods that must be implemented by any class that claims to implement the interface.

Comment: and what happens when i pass 'c' along with the array to be sorted?

Comment: so i can have any interface right? i can make a new interface say public interface abc{ //methods };
i dont have to provide a particular method in there, why does it happen with comparable, that i have to provide compareTo in it. Is it some standardized interface?

Comment: Yes you may define any interface you like with any set of methods. And yes, Comparable is an already defined system interface. See my links.

Comment: so when i am implementing comparator, then my BOX class need not implement the comparable interface as the basis for comparison will be provided by the comparator only?

Comment: Generally, Comparator implementation would not use a classes Comparable implementation. What would be the point since they would result in the same order and passing a Comparator to sort is optional. Most implementation of Comparator use some different comparison mechanism to order the elements of a class. It usually uses getters to retrieve fields from the class upon which to base the comparison.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can define as many methods as you want in a `Comparable`, as long as you implement `compareTo`. This method can be used in many situations where the class is checked for comparation. For example, when inserting instances into an ordered `TreeSet`. `compareTo` provides a general ordering rule for all instances of the class.
2. [`Arrays.sort`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28java.lang.Object%5b%5d%29) orders the array in the *natural order* of its elements. That is, using `compareTo`.
3. You can use `Comparator` to define a custom ordering rule. Like when you have a table you can sort by any of its columns. You could define a `Comparator` for each of its columns, and you could still have a class-inherent ordering rule (as in related to the reality the Class represents) defined in the class' `compareTo`.

Answer (score 0):

Implementing [Comparable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) obligates you to provide an implementation for [compareTo()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo%28T%29).

All elements in the Object array passed to the [Arrays.sort(Object[])](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29) method must implement [Comparable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html). If you want to use a [Comparator](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) instead, you have to use an [Arrays.sort()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28T%5B%5D,%20java.util.Comparator%29) method that takes a `Comparator` as a parameter. The method you use in your example above takes a `Comparator` as the second parameter - hence the need to provide `c1` in the method call.